# Espresso - check if the TextView exists in the ListView

Tags: android, junit, junit4, android-espresso

I want to check displaying of **Save €XX** in the list. **Save €XX** is a TextView that can be `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE`. I use JUnit 4 and Espresso 2.2.1.

I tried to check it like this:

```
onView(withText(startsWith("Save"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

but always get an error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with text: a string starting with "Save"' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
```

Is there a way to if the TextView exists in the ListView with Espresso?

**UPDATE**

I also tried to use `onData`:

```
onData(hasToString(startsWith("Save")))
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.suggestion_list_view)).atPosition(0)
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

but it seems that `onData` works with data layer but not the view layer. Therefore, I receive the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No data found matching: with toString() a string starting with "Save" contained values: <[Data: ...]>
```

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After several tries, I found the way.

In this case, we should use a combined approach and work with both data and view layers. We access the `ListView` by `ID` and choose the first item. Then check it for the **'Save'** text.

```
onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list_view))
                .atPosition(0)
                .onChildView(withId(R.id.suggestion_saving))
                .check(matches(withText(startsWith("Save"))));
```

Works like a charm. Enjoy!